# How to skip the case statement if condition fails (using Java)?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have written a code which fetches the input file as a dataframe.

I need to copy the value of the particular columns which are present in the dataframe to a new column. for creating a new column i've used 'withcolumn'.

```
    Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(FilePath);
            
            List<String> h1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            h1 = Arrays.asList(df1.columns());
            Dataset<Row> df;
            df = df1;

for(String field:h1) 
        {
        switch (field) 
        {
        case "A":
        df = df1.withColumn("first",df1.col("A")); 
        case "B": 
        df = df.withColumn("second",df1.col("B")); 
        case "C": 
        df = df.withColumn("third",df1.col("C")); 
        case "D": 
        df = df.withColumn("fourth",df1.col("D"));
```

My concern is how to skip the value case statement if the particular column name is not present.

For example in the above code if case "C" is not present in the dataframe it should skip and go to the next case. In my case it is throwing error like "cannot resolve "c".

Please share some suggestion on how to skip the case or is there any other way to do so. TIA

Comment: Use break; And also, normally in a switch statement you should have a break; ending each case, otherwise all the remaining cases will run.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer yes if i use break it will stop right there and come out of the loop nah? In my case it should skip that particular case and continue with the rest of the statements.

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the innermost context, in your case the `switch`. You need that otherwise you'll fall through all following cases. Also it is good practice to include the `default` case, which is used when none of the other cases match.

Comment: @QBrute even after including break in all case statement it doesn't skip the case "c" which is not present in the dataframe. It throughs error like cannot resolve column "c".

Comment: @QBrute and ive used default statement too like " defaut: System.out.println("Column doesn't exist");

Comment: @George, just to be sure, do spark load the file as you expect it to be? some have problems with trailing space, others have issue with csv separators. i'd bet, `break` is mandatory and even though you add it and still got errors, it must be other factor, the file input. `default` in `switch-case` statement is used as fallback behavior should none of the provided `case` match. it doesnt handle errors from spark. there is too little information to work on your question.